# Why does every cell in a column get the formula when I try to apply formula to a single cell?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a column of formulas that refer to another table, and I want to be able to sort my new column without that affecting the values.  I am trying:

```
' dataTable is a ListObject
Dim statusCol As ListColumn
Dim statusRange as Range
Dim statusCell As Range
Dim statusIndex as Integer

Set statusCol = dataTable.ListColumns.Add(2)
dataTable.HeaderRowRange(2) = "Status"
Set statusRange = statusCol.DataBodyRange
statusIndex = 1
For Each statusCell in statusRange.Cells
    statusCell.formula = "=IF(INDEX(MatchColumn," & statusIndex & "), ""X"", ""Y"")"
    statusIndex = statusIndex + 1
Next statusCell
```

This loop should, if I understand it correctly, put a different value of statusIndex in each cell.  But when I step through it in the debugger, as soon as I set the first cell, the formula is set for every cell.  So when I have 25 rows of data, I end up with the formula in every cell having a formula of

```
=IF(INDEX(MatchColumn, 25), "X", "Y")
```

whereas I want the first row to have the number 1, the second to have 2 ...

So why does Excel set every cell in the column every time around the loop?  And how can I stop it doing that?

Comment: when entering formulas in a table - as you noticed - the formula will automatically fill in for all rows in the table. However, it should recognize each row separately. But you are trying to put a reference outside of the table object, it is not recognizing this. As a workaround, can you place the formula column maybe one column away from the table, so that Excel does not recognize it as part of the table?

Comment: @ScottHoltzman: thanks for the pointer, I'll have a go.  Can I then copy the column back in without wrecking the formulas?

Comment: Your statement : `Set statusRange = statusCol.DataBodyRange` mean that you are taking the data range (range with headers) of the 2 columns that you just created. And then you loop on every cell in these 2 columns. So it might be easier to do : `statusRange.Cells(1,1)..formula = "=IF(INDEX(MatchColumn," & statusIndex & "), ""X"", ""Y"")"` if you only want the first cell to have that formula!

Comment: @HamishDowner - you'll have to do a little trial and error on copying the column back in. I don't know. If copying it back in doesn't work, also try deleting the extra column between the table and your formula. That may be another trick to make it work, too.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I have found to get this rigth is to add one more column to the table with idexes number and then use this code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D9").Formula = "=IF(INDEX(MatchColumn, A" & statusIndex & "), ""X"", ""Y"")"
```

Notice that I added an extra `A` on the formula.

In this example my A column contain indexes number, look like this

[image]